# How can I create new Python file PyCharm with shortcut

Tags: pycharm

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>insert</kbd> opens a dialog to choose the file type I want to creat.
Can I specify that I want to create py file directly without choosing?

Comment: I don't think is possible without choosing. However `ctrl` + `Alt` + `Shift` + `Insert`will help

Answer (score 11):

1. Go to File->Setting->Keymap
2. Search "new"
3. Under "Pyhon Community Edition" there will bean option of "Python
   File"
4. Add new shortcut to this option (SHIFT+N is usually unassigned)

Comment: Do you happen to know how to set it in the Mac pro version?