# Keyboard shortcut with PyCharm to create new file

Tags: pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

Good day, I am currently using PyCharm 2021.1.1 (Community Edition) on macOS 11.4.

I would like to use the keyboard shortcut to generate a new Python file.

When using the following: Command + N, I get the following screen:

[image]

My expectation when clicking Command + N, is the following screen:

[image]

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create new Python file PyCharm with shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51905961/how-can-i-create-new-python-file-pycharm-with-shortcut)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Command+N* is Generate shortcut if you're focusing on the editor. You can confirm that by using Find Actions by Shortcut in the settings: *Preferences | Keymap*.
[image]

There are a couple of ways to use New as a shortcut for creating a new file.

- Switch focus to Project View (*Command+1* by default) and press *Command+N*.
- Assign a new shortcut to New action in the settings. It has the benefit that you can use the pop-up *exactly* from the editor pane *without* switching to Project View.[image]