# How do I open a new .py file in pycharm using keyboard shortcut in windows 10?

Tags: pycharm

[How can I create new Python file PyCharm with shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51905961/how-can-i-create-new-python-file-pycharm-with-shortcut)

This doesn't work now.

[Keyboard shortcut with PyCharm to create new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67770625/keyboard-shortcut-with-pycharm-to-create-new-file)

This one is for mac os only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to File->Setting->Keymap

[image]

2. Search "new"

[image]

3. Double click on the Python file.
4. Add any shortcut you want. In my case, I have configured Shift +N

[image]